# How can i print the result outside the function in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have return the function for getting all the parameter documents in express.js .i want to print the result outside the find function.how can get this done help me out

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
var parameterObject = [];
var produtObject = [];
Parameter.find().exec(function (err, Parameters) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    parameterObject.push(Parameters);

  });

  Product.find().exec(function (err, Products) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    produtObject.push(Products);

  });
  console.log(parameterObject);
  console.log(produtObject);

}
```

now console i am getting empty [] object .

Comment: how come its duplicate thats is diff my question is different

Comment: Actually it is not different, the callback you pass in `exec()` is asynchronous, and you want to make it synchronous. I suggest you research a bit into `generators`, `promises` and ES7 `async`/`await`

Comment: @mojo have you fix it now?

Comment: yes this i want to solve @NewbeeDev

Comment: @mojo anyway whats the purpose you want to access it outside?

Comment: i want to calculate parameter values with product price

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737716/how-can-get-two-collection-documents-and-calculate-points-using-express-js @NewbeeDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access that outside since `Parameter.find()` is asynchronous
but you can pass a callback which pass the variable `parameterObject`

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
var parameterObject = [];

    function MethodName(callback) {
        Parameter.find().exec(function (err, Parameters) {
            if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
            parameterObject.push(Parameters);
            return callback(parameterObject);
        });
    }

    MethodName(function(parameterObject) {
        console.log(parameterObject);
    })

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737716/how-can-get-two-collection-documents-and-calculate-points-using-express-js @NewbeeDev

Comment: can you check that sir

Comment: help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931821/how-to-combine-two-collection-based-on-idtransectionid-using-node-js @NewbeeDev