# How can get two collection documents and calculate points using express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

```
exports.show = = function(req, res) {
    var userdata = [{
        "productcode": "9563456789",
        "cost": "1000"

    }, {
        "productcode": "8756348947",
        "cost": "5600"

    }]



    var parameterObject = [];

    Parameter.find().exec(function(err, Parameters) {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
        }
        // i want to push Parameters[0].value to parameterObject
        parameterObject.push({
            pointvalue: Parameters[0].value
        });


    });


    for (var i = 0; i < userdata.length; i++) {

        Product.find({
            'productcode': userdata[i].productcode
        }).exec(function(err, Products) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            var point = 0;
            if (!Products) {
                point = 0;
            } else if (Products[0].product.point > 0) {
                point = Products[0].product.point;
            }
            if (point > 0) {

                // here i am not getting userdata[i].cost
                //parameterObject.pointvalue value also not getting
                totalprice = userdata[i].cost / parameterObject.pointvalue * point;
            }


        });
    }
};
```

Here i have written function for calculating totalprice. i have mentioned userdata(this is my req.body).

Expectation :

i need to store Parameters objects in some variable to access where ever i want.
i want to pass userdata object in Product.find() function

how can i calculate this

```
totalprice= userdata[i].cost/parameterObject.pointvalue) * point);
```

Comment: help me out @newbee-dev

Comment: if you expect someone to read your code, understand your problem and come up with a solution, please take the time to at least format it! It's like 3 keystrokes in any IDE/editor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @DrakaSAN can you pls help me out

Comment: @mojo: Yes I could, but if you took the time to read the duplicate, or anything about asynchronous programming, you should have understood where is your error. Your attitude of "plz giv me ze codzzz" doesn't help at all.

Comment: @DrakaSAN  i did not understand that and i dont think both are same

Comment: They are, you just use Promises instead of callback, and a part of the accepted answer scecifically adress their use

Comment: if you don mind can you read my function @DrakaSAN

Comment: I did, and even reformatted it. The error is simple and nagging me will not help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128699/discussion-between-mojo-and-drakasan).

Comment: m not nagging you @DrakaSAN

Comment: @mojo you can you node js promises for that. you better search some ducumentation with that

Comment: im new to this sir help me out @NewbeeDev

Comment: @mojo you haven't fix it yet?

Comment: not working sir @NewbeeDev

Comment: @mojo did you receive errors? whats the output?

Comment: its not working bcoz of my userdata got changed kno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exports.show = = function(req, res) {
    var userdata = [{
        "productcode": "9563456789",
        "cost": "1000"

    }, {
        "productcode": "8756348947",
        "cost": "5600"

    }]

    var parameterObject = [];

    Parameter.find().exec(function(err, Parameters) {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
        }
        // i want to push Parameters[0].value to parameterObject 
        parameterObject.push({
            pointvalue: Parameters[0].value
        });

        return FindProducts(parameterObject, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

    function FindProducts(parameterObject, callback) {
        for (var i = 0; i < userdata.length; i++) {
            var totalprice = 0;
            findProduct(i, parameterObject,  function(i, price) {
                totalprice += price;
                if (i <= userdata.length) {
                    return callback({
                        "userid": "myuserid",
                        "total": totalprice
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function findProduct(i, parameterObject, callback) {
        Product.find({
            'productcode': userdata[i].productcode
        }).exec(function(err, Products) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            var point = 0;
            if (!Products) {
                point = 0;
            } else if (Products[0].product.point > 0) {
                point = Products[0].product.point;
            }
            if (point > 0) {

                // here you can now get the value of userdata[i].cost 
                // here you can now get the value of parameterObject 
                totalprice = userdata[i].cost / parameterObject[0].pointvalue * point;

                return callback(i, totalprice);
            }

        });
    }


};
```

Comment: not running this function Product.find() and i add console.log(userdata[i].productcode) .its continusly printing only 9563456789 value in console

Comment: Where did you put the console?

Comment: inside while loop

Comment: while (i < userdata.length) {
//console.log(userdata[i].productcode);

Comment: Did you try to put it inside find() callback

Comment: Where i need to add callback sir@NewbeeDev

Comment: @mojo let us continue in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128773/discussion-between-mojo-and-newbee-dev).

Comment: @mojo the chat has gone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501008/how-to-do-find-in-node-and-mongodb.help

Answer (score 1):

You can use **promises** when you want to use the result of two functions and later use it for further computation.

In your case, you can execute the two asynchronous functions in parallel. It can look like this.

```
Promise.all([
    asyncFunc1(),
    asyncFunc2(),
])
.then(function(result){
    // result is an array and has the response of the functions which is
    // result[0] and result[1]
    ···
   // you can manipulate the result of the functions here
})
.catch(function(err){
    // Receives rejection/error among the Promises
    ···
});
```

Here asyncFunc1() will be your first find function

asyncFunc2() will be your second find function.

The result[0] and result[1] will be the results of the functions respectively.

Later you can use the result to do further computations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124705/based-on-value-how-to-create-new-document-using-node-js-mongodb