# How to combine two collection based on id(transectionid) using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i have transection and purchase collections,which is contaning transection and purchase details now i want to convert it into single collection.
based on transectionid we need to combine the documents

Below is my transection collection data's

```
{

    "transectionid": "1",
    "transectionamount": "2000",
    "transectiondate": "2016-07-12 19:22:28",

},
{

    "transectionid": "2",
    "transectionamount": "1000",
    "transectiondate": "2016-07-12 20:17:11",

}
```

below is my purchase collection datas

```
{

    "purchaseid": "1",
    "transectionid": "1",
    "itemprice": "1200",
    "itemcode": "edcvb",
    "itemquantity": "1",


},
{

    "purchaseid": "2",
    "transectionid": "1",
    "itemprice": "800",
    "itemcode": "dfgh",
    "itemquantity": "2",


},
{

    "purchaseid": "3",
    "transectionid": "2",
    "itemprice": "1000",
    "itemcode": "zxcvb",
    "itemquantity": "1",


}
```

my expectation result :
this is how order collecion should store 
    {

```
        "transectionid" : "1",
        "transectionamount": "2000",
        "transectiondate": "2016-07-12 19:22:28",
        "items" : [
                {
                    "purchaseid": "1",
                    "itemprice":"1200",
                    "itemcode": "edcvb",
                    "itemquantity": "1",
                },
                {
                    "purchaseid": "2",
                    "itemprice": "800",
                    "itemcode": "dfgh",
                    "itemquantity": "2",
                }
        ]
}
{

        "transectionid" : "2",
        "transectionamount": "1000",
        "transectiondate": "2016-07-12 20:17:11",
        "items" : [
                {
                    "purchaseid": "3",
                    "itemprice":"1000",
                    "itemcode": "zxcvb",
                    "itemquantity": "1",
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: take a look on  $addToSet once. This might work for you.

Comment: would you like to migrate in one collection or just return to client side as expected  result?

Comment: i would like to write in controller or schema not in client

Comment: Are you using mongoose? if yes it would be better if shown your schema

Comment: im using mongoose only

Comment: have not schema ?

Comment: m having mongoose and schema both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129785/discussion-between-shaishab-roy-and-its-me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your expected result you may want to get all transaction with populated purchase data as items.

In your structure `transectionid` is `String` type and you may not used `ref` in your schema. so populate `transectionid` you should use `$lookup` because we can define `from`,`localField` and `foreignField`. for that you don't need to use `ref` in your schema.

and you should add `items: []` in your `Transaction` schema because if you didn't add that you may not get `items` in your result.

in `transaction` controller can add this function to get all transaction with `purchase` data as items.

for `from` field in `$lookup` you should use lower case and plural form of collection name because when mongoose create collection made it plural. like your exported schema name `PurchasesData` then it will create like `purchasesdatas`

like:

```
exports.getTransactions = function(req,res){ 

  Transection.aggregate([ 
    {$lookup:{from:"purchases", localField:"transectionid", foreignField:"transectionid", as:"items"}} 
  ]).exec(function(err, result) { 
    if(err) { 
      console.log('error============', err); 
      return res.status(400).send("error occurred"); 
    }else{ 
      console.log(result); 
      return res.status(200).send(result); 
    } 
  }); 
};
```

Comment: i am getting error in mongodb .can you please help me out @Shaishab Roy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542270/how-can-i-combine-multiple-collection-into-one-collection-using-with-lookup-mon

Answer (score 2):

well using javascript and just some for cycles you can do this.

```
var transactionsSize = transactions.length;
var purchasesSize = purchases.length
var finalArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(transactions));

for(var i = 0 ; i < transactionsSize; i++ ) {
    for(var j = 0; j < purchasesSize; j++) {
        if(transactions[i].transactionid == purchases[j].transactionid) {
            if(!finalArray[i].items) {
                finalArray[i].items = [];
                finalArray[i].items.push(purchases[j]);
            } else {
                finalArray[i].items.push(purchases[j]);
            }
         }
     }
}
```

here is a working fiddle(note that some names are not the same as your input'transections' for example) https://jsfiddle.net/yph9yc86/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542270/how-can-i-combine-multiple-collection-into-one-collection-using-with-lookup-mon

Answer (score 2):

If you are using native mongo driver, you need to implement it yourself.

If you are using mongoose, take a look at [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), and even [cross DB population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#cross-db-populate), as they already did all the work.

For example, according to your schemas:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var transactionSchema = Schema({
  transectiondate: Date,
  transectionid : Number,
  transectionamount: Number,
  items: [{ type: Number, ref: 'Item' }]
});

var itemSchema = Schema({
  transectionid: Number,
  purchaseid : Number,
  itemprice: Number,
  itemcode: String,
  itemquantity: Number,
});

var Transaction = mongoose.model('Transaction', transactionSchema);
var Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);

Transaction
.find({})
.populate('items')
.exec(function (err, transactinos) {
  console.log(transactinos);
});
```

Comment: i am having two different collections not like this

Comment: This is 2 collections. Each schema is a collection. Like I wrote, even if they are 2 collections where each collection is located on a different database, mongoose can do the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542270/how-can-i-combine-multiple-collection-into-one-collection-using-with-lookup-mon